# switching from view 1 to view 2 without pressing any buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

How to switch from view1 to view 2 without having any button pressed. In my  views i have is uiimageview and uitextview

With the NSTimer i m trying to do this

in the viewdidload method by using the following code:

In the firstviewcontroller.h file

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController 
{
    NSTimer *SwitchingTimer;   
}
```

In the firstviewcontroller.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   SwitchingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self      selector:@selector(SwitchView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)SwitchViews:(id)sender
```

In the secondviewcontroller.m file

```
-(void) SwitchView
{
SecondViewController *SecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
SecondView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:SecondView animated:YES];
[SwitchingTimer invalidate];
self.SwitchingTimer = nil;

}
```

but nothing is  happening. Can someone please tell me what i m  missing in my code. Will appreciate help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to the run loop:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SwitchingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self      selector:@selector(SwitchView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: SwitchingTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

Also, you could rename `-(void)SwitchView` to `-(void)switchViewTimerDidFire:(NSTimer *)timer`. From the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a):

> [...] The selector must have the following signature:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

> The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code that are worth mentioning though I am not sure if those will provide you a solution.

Why do you want to repeat the timer every 2 seconds. I think you just want to switch to next view only once and if so then dont repeat the timer. So no need to invalidate the timer.

Your code for the `SwitchView` method is leaking memory. Please make sure that the `SecondView` is released after presenting the modal view(in case you are not using ARC).

Please follow the standard naming conventions. For eg: methods and variables should start with lowercase.

Regarding your issue please make sure that the nib name is correct and you are getting a valid object for the second view controller. You can check by using `NSLog`. Also ensure that the method Switchview is called. Try putting a break point and verify that it is called.

**Another Option**

If you just want to switch the view only once you can go for another option which does not make use of the NSTimer. For this, you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. This is just another option for the scenario I mentioned above.

Comment: Note that when using ARC, `SwitchView` is not leaking anymore.